# How to change Php currency type to Dollar sign?

Tags: postgresql

I am wondering why in my local, if I input value in Money type it will display
Php0.00 I want to display like $0.00

I tried to input value from Php0.00 to $0.00 but an error display.

[image]

maybe my setting it's default in Php, that's why I tried to changed it in setting but still does not work, any idea? thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PHP also has money_format().

Here's an example:

```
echo money_format('$%i', 3.4); // echos '$3.40'
```

Check documentation for more...

Comment: Not this mate, this is about the row value, not how to get value in row then change the format.

Comment: Talking Philippine Peso here, not Pretty Horrible Programming